# Why is the label "container" on this checkbox, NOT allowing the text to be checkable along with the checkbox itself (to toggle the checkbox on & off)?

Tags: forms, checkbox, label

This checkbox works, but using the label as a container around the input element is supposed to allow the long text to be included in the area that users can check on to toggle the checkbox on and off. It's not.

Why is it not allowing the long text to toggle the checkbox? How do I make it include it? I only know HTML, PHP and CSS so am sticking with those.

The code inside a form:

```
<label for "membership">
<input type="checkbox" name="membership" id="membership">Check off box to join. Cost is $20 to join the group as an associate member to cover the expense of mailings to keep you informed of upcoming events</label>
```

I tried the same idea with a radio button instead of checkbox and that don't work either.

```
  <label for "membership"><input type="radio" name="amount" id="amount" value="15">Select button for membership. Cost is $20 to cover mailing costs.</label>
```

I've put them both into a snippet:

```html
<form action="/Online/DonateOnline.php" name="form" target="_self">

<label for "membership">
    <input type="checkbox" name="membership" id="membership"
    >Add $20 to join the group as an associate member to cover the expense of mailings to keep you informed of upcoming events</label>
 
 <br> <br>  <br>  
    
   <label for "radiomem">
    <input type="radio" name="radiomem" id="radiomem">Same thing but with a radio button.  Also doing it shorter didn't fix it either.</label>
    
    </form>
```

**ADDITIONAL INFO:
I tested in another browser, MS Edge, and it works. The longer texts is check-able. But it does not work in Firefox. The longer text is not checkable. Is there a way to get it to work in FF?

Meanwhile, it works in android. It's much more crucial that it work on a small screen, so if FF users have to be more exacting when clicking, it's not the end of the world.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out with testing, that the longer label text is checkable (works to toggle the buttons on and off), when using other browsers. So it works in Microsoft Edge, and on Android. It does not work in Firefox.

I don't have a solution for Firefox yet.